# Firebase - Handle cloud events within NestJS Framework

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, nestjs

I'm using [NestJS](https://nestjs.com) as my backend Framework and Firebase.

To integrate Nest with Firebase on HTTP requests is simple as attaching the express instance of nest to Firebase:

```
const server: Express = express();

const bootstrap = async (expressInstance: Express) => {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, expressInstance);
  await app.listen(3000);
  await app.init();
};

bootstrap(server);

exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(server);
```

But what about the other Google Functions (such as pubsub, firestore, auth, etc.)?

I'm building a subscription application, and I depend on `functions.pubsub` to check at the end of every day which subscriptions should I charge. It requires writing business logic that I want to write withing NestJs.

I'm trying to achieve something like this (in a nutshell):

```
functions.pubsub
    .topic('topic')
    .onPublish(app.getService(Service).method);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out I was very close to the solution. instead of `getService`, I had to use `get`, like so:

```
const bootstrap = async (expressInstance: Express) => {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, expressInstance);
  await app.init();

  return app;
};

const main = bootstrap(server);

export const subscriptions = functions
  .pubsub
  .topic('cron-topic')
  .onPublish((context, message) => main.then(app => {
    return app.get(SubscribeService).initDailyCharges(context, message));
  });
```

Comment: What minimal memory amount should be set to the Cloud Function execution environment to run Nest?

Comment: @ViacheslavDobromyslov I haven't had any issues with memory. Just used the default amount back then

Comment: Thanks. Found here https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/1519 it consumes about 32Mb.

Answer (score 2):

Found a new solution for standalone applications:
https://docs.nestjs.com/standalone-applications

You don't need to bootstrap NestJS with Express server to handle PubSub messages.

```
export const subscriptions = functions
  .pubsub
  .topic('cron-topic')
  .onPublish((context, message) => {
    const app = await NestFactory.create(ApplicationModule);
    return app.get(SubscribeService).initDailyCharges(context, message);
  });
```