# How can I use Nest with Firestore Functions?

Tags: typescript, firebase, nestjs

I'm looking for a way to incorporate Nest with Firestore function events. I've already seen this post: [Firebase - Handle cloud events within NestJS Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53307541/firebase-handle-cloud-events-within-nestjs-framework), but am looking for a way to take advantage of nest decorators and just have the class get bootstraped automatically. Is it possible to get the context of the top class decorator and apply it to the method decorator level? I'm hoping to implement it as follows.

(e.g.)

```
@FsController('users/{uid}') // context?
export class UsersFsController {

  @Update() // functions.firestore.document('users/{uid}').onUpdate
  onUpdate(change, context) {
    // handle
  }

  @Delete() // functions.firestore.document('users/{uid}').onDelete
  onDelete(snap, context) {
    //   handle
  }

}
```

Comment: Sounds like this could be a cool library to add into the NestJS ecosystem. [This library](https://github.com/jmcdo29/nestjs-commander) for command line functions may be of use to be a start point.